# Serilog using EnrichDiagnosticContext with additional properties not being logged in SignalR Hub

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5, serilog

I have recently implemented Serilog logging into my ASP.NET Core/.NET5 web app that uses SignalR.  I'm using the Elasticsearch sink and everything is largely working as expected.  I decided to add some additional HttpContext properties to be logged on each request, so I went down the road of extending the call to **UseSerilogRequestLogging()** in StartUp.cs as to enrich the diagnostic context with a couple of extra properties (mainly because this seemed like the simplest way to do it):

```cs
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(options =>
{
    options.EnrichDiagnosticContext = (diagnosticContext, httpContext) =>
    {
        diagnosticContext.Set("HttpRequestClientIP", httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress);
        diagnosticContext.Set("UserName", httpContext.User?.Identity?.Name == null ? "(anonymous)" : httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    };
});
```

At first, this seemed to work as expected until I noticed it wasn't ***always*** working.  I really want the extra properties logged on all log records written, and it seems to work fine on log records that are written automatically by Serilog when typical HTTP GETs, HTTP POSTs, etc. occur...  But in my Signalr Hub class, I have a couple of places where I'm manually writing my own log records like `Logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "whatever..")`, but these extra properties are simply not there on these records.

What am I missing here?  Is it something about this being in a Signalr Hub that makes them unavailable?  Or perhaps there's something I'm doing wrong with my Logger.Log() calls?

Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks-

Answer (score 1):

It's not gonna to work with signalR.

Behind the screen, `app.UseSerilogRequestLogging` make use of a middleware in the request pipeline, that call `RequestLoggingMiddleware` as what you can see in detail [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/blob/dev/src/Serilog.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/RequestLoggingMiddleware.cs).

SignalR use the first Http request to setting to connection up to websocket, which won't goes through the pipeline at all. Therefore, doesn't have anything to do with `RequestLoggingMiddleware`, which you are using to logging out the request.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up going with a couple of custom Enrichers.  I did experiment briefly with middleware vs enrichers and they both seem to work as expected.  Both always added the additional properties to all log entries.  I'm still not quite sure I understand why the DiagnosticContext option behaves the way it does, unless it is simply due to the logging in question being in a SignalR hub as @Gordon Khanh Ng. posted.  If that were the root of the problem though, you wouldn't think the enrichers or middleware would work either.